# ASP.NET MVC3 login not for long

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, asp.net-membership, custom-membershipprovider

I am using own membership provider and I can login and logout. When I login, it is been login just for a moment and then no user is login. I don´t know where is problem but when I am trying it on my computer (IIS Express) the user is login for long time but when I upload my website to my hosting provider then the user is login just for several seconds. Thanks for help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the application runs in a web farm you must ensure that all nodes of this web farm have the same [`machineKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx). If they do not have the same machine keys if the authentication cookie is emitted on server 1, and the next request is served by server 2 it won't be able to decrypt this cookie. You could try setting their value in the web.config of your application.